# Combobox interaction issue

Tags: wpf, combobox

I have a wpf user control library with three combo boxes (cmbBox1,cmbBox2 and cmbBox3). Initially the comboboxes 2 & 3 are disabled. User first selects and item from cmbBox1. Based on the user selection the items in cmbBox2 and cmbBox3 are populated. My code works fine for the first time. However it breaks when the user changes the selection in box1. Here is my code:

```
private void cmbBox1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    this.cmbBox2.Items.Clear();
    this.cmbBox3.Items.Clear();

    //this.cmbBox2.ItemsSource = new object[] {};
    //this.cmbBox3.ItemsSource = new object[] {};

    string Box1String = cmbBox1.SelectedItem.ToString();

    if (this.cmbBox1.SelectedIndex == 0)
    {
        this.cmbBox2.ItemsSource = new object[] { "Item2_0"};
        this.cmbBox3.ItemsSource = new object[] { "Item3_0"};
    }
    else if (this.cmbBox1.SelectedIndex == 1)
    {
        this.cmbBox2ItemsSource = new object[] { "Item2_1"};
        this.cmbBox3.ItemsSource = new object[] { "Item3_1"};
    }

}

private void cmbBox2_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string Box2String = cmbBox2.SelectedItem.ToString();

    //Rest of the code//

}
```

When the form opens up the code works perfectly. Now afer the selections are made, if the user goes back and changes the selection in combobox1, then code crashes with error:

System.NullReferenceException: 'Object reference not set to an instance of an object.'

at the first line of the Combobox2 SelectionIndexChanged event. I thought it is due to the fact that I am clearing the items in Combobox2 and combobox3 when any change happens in combobox1. So I tried commenting thoses lines out, but was not successful either. I currently have no clue why this is occurring and any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution that fixed the issue. What I did was to delink the selectionchanged event for comboboxes 2 & 3 within the selection changed event of combobox1. Later after I bind the items for comboboxes 2 & 3 I again assign the function to the selection changed event. Here is the code that worked.

```
private void cmbBox1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    //this.cmbBox2.Items.Clear();
    //this.cmbBox3.Items.Clear();

    //this.cmbBox2.ItemsSource = new object[] {};
    //this.cmbBox3.ItemsSource = new object[] {};

    string Box1String = cmbBox1.SelectedItem.ToString();
    this.cmbBox2.SelectionChanged -= new SelectionChangedEventHandler(cmbBox2_SelectedIndexChanged);
    this.cmbBox3.SelectionChanged -= new SelectionChangedEventHandler(cmbBox3_SelectedIndexChanged);

    if (this.cmbBox1.SelectedIndex == 0)
    {
        this.cmbBox2.ItemsSource = new object[] { "Item2_0"};
        this.cmbBox3.ItemsSource = new object[] { "Item3_0"};
    }
    else if (this.cmbBox1.SelectedIndex == 1)
    {
        this.cmbBox2ItemsSource = new object[] { "Item2_1"};
        this.cmbBox3.ItemsSource = new object[] { "Item3_1"};
    }
    this.cmbBox2.SelectionChanged += new SelectionChangedEventHandler(cmbBox2_SelectedIndexChanged);
    this.cmbBox3.SelectionChanged += new SelectionChangedEventHandler(cmbBox3_SelectedIndexChanged);
}

private void cmbBox2_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string Box2String = cmbBox2.SelectedItem.ToString();

    //Rest of the code//

}

private void cmbBox3_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string Box3String = cmbBox3.SelectedItem.ToString();

    //Rest of the code//

}
```